# Fast moving bodies miss the collision sometimes in Box2d, AndEngine

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

I have a Fast Moving Body(A) which is dynamic. It is supposed to collide with another Body(B). A collides with B, but sometimes it passes the Body B without collision. This is totally random behavior. I must have that collision. Kindly guide why it is acting like this, randomly.

Comment: check for CCD ( Continuous Collision Detection ) option in Box2D if avail.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The effect of one object passing through another due to large movement in a single timestep is called **tunneling**.

Box2D uses Continuous Collision Detection between dynamic and *static* objects to solve this problem. However, your case (dynamic v.s. dynamic) isn't automatically handled, so it's just a random dice throw whether your objects happen to be in colliding positions at the exact moment the collisions are evaluated.

From the [Box2d Manual](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html#_Toc258082978):

> Normally CCD is not used between dynamic bodies. This is done to keep
>   performance reasonable. In some game scenarios you need dynamic bodies
>   to use CCD. For example, you may want to shoot a high speed bullet at
>   a stack of dynamic bricks. Without CCD, the bullet might tunnel
>   through the bricks.
>
> Fast moving objects in Box2D can be labeled as bullets. Bullets will
>   perform CCD with both static and dynamic bodies. You should decide
>   what bodies should be bullets based on your game design. If you decide
>   a body should be treated as a bullet, use the following setting.
>
> bodyDef.bullet = true;
>
> The bullet flag only affects dynamic bodies.
>
> Box2D performs continuous collision sequentially, so bullets may miss
>   fast moving bodies.

Comment: Thanks Paul, for a good answer. Well, I have used, what is mentioned above. It is working fine. I have tested my app number of times, and didn't get the problem again. It seems that "bullet" is fired in the right direction. :-)