# libgdx box2d dynamic body passed through dynamic body

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I got 2 dynamic bodies. One is large and falling down, another one is player body, which will move upwards with screen taps.

Player body has a limit boundaries checking like this:

```
  if(body.getPosition().x + this.getWidth()/2 >  Constant.GAME_WIDTH)
    { 
        body.setTransform(Constant.GAME_WIDTH - this.getWidth()/2 , body.getPosition().y, 0 );
    }
```

Each screen tap will move player body upwards with coding:

```
 body.applyLinearImpulse(FORCE ,CENTER ,true);
```

However, when the falling big dynamic body comes intact with player body, few taps on the player body will make player body to goes through the big dynamic body.

I want the big dynamic body to push player body down, not by going through player body, please help.

Left is the big dynamic body falling down, right is the player body, apparently passing through the big dynamic body at edge.

[image: photo of 2 dynamics bodies]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fast moving bodies miss the collision sometimes in Box2d, AndEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307837/fast-moving-bodies-miss-the-collision-sometimes-in-box2d-andengine)

Comment: After setting isbullet to true, now the player body need greater force to passing through big dynamic body. Can i know any chance to totally avoid this?